# Finding the points where a complex function is differentiable?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Determine the points $z \in \mathbb C$ for which $h(z) = e^\overline z$ is differentiable. (Here $\overline z$ denotes the complex
conjugate of z.)

I have attempted the question and have found the Cauchy Riemann equations but I'm not sure what to do next? Any help will be appreciated thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that a function is complex differentiable *if and only if* it satysfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations at the point.

So, lets think as your function as a function from $\mathbb{R^2}$ to $\mathbb{R^2}$. Denoting $z=x+yi$ we have $f(x,y)=e^{x-yi}=e^{x} e^{i(-y)}=e^x(\cos y-i\sin y)=(e^x\cos y,-e^x\sin y)$

Use now the Cauchy-Riemann equations to see where $f$ is differentiable.

The Cauchy-Riemann equations "helps us translate" functions from $\mathbb{R^2}$ to $\mathbb{R^2}$ to functions from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Woah ! You are right , what I had written was completely wrong...

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I think I understand now! :)